# How to make Windows 7 boot animation show up on a screen with 1024x600 resolution?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I've read [somewhere](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:thehotfix.net/forums/index.php?/topic/25607-windows-7-boot-screen-on-netbook/) that the Windows 7 boot animation is only shown when the screen resolution height is 768 or above. However, I have a netbook that has 1024x600 max resolution. I want to know if there's any way to make it show the boot animation even with such a small height. Are there any patches available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [BCDEdit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731662%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to set the "bootup user experience" to "Standard" mode to get the Win7 boot, but if doesn't help then it probably isn't going to happen, due to screen resolution.

So here's what you want to try:

`bcdedit /set bootux standard`

Or just remove the Bootux value, which is equivalent to setting it to 'standard', with `bcdedit /deletevalue bootux`.

You can also set Bootux to 'disabled' to have NO boot screen.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a modified resource DLL or file that will allow it on smaller screens. I tried your suggestions (both) and none of them worked.